# Connect two TVs to one computer with different content on each

Tags: hdmi, split-window

I want to connect two different TVs with one computer and display different things on each TV. Is it possible?

Comment: This is pretty vague. What type of content? Which graphics card / outputs are available? Which OS are you using? Nearly every OS on the market supports multidisplay setups.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two HDMI ports on your computer for this. You can do this by having one TV connected to the display port on your motherboard for the integrated graphics and the other to your discrete video card (which you will need). After this, you just need to set up extended desktop to show different things on the two displays.

Another option which might be possible for some setups (mostly should work) is to connect one TV to your VGA port (maybe using a cheap converter) and the other to the HDMI on the motherboard.

Comment: That's work too, "one to HDMI and other one to VGA"

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on your PC exactly what you can do.

My new PC for example has 4 mini-display port, a HDMI and a DVI port on the one graphics card.  I could drive a few screens at once, and don't need to resort to motherboard/CPU based graphics chipsets.
My old machine had Dual DVI ports and a single HDMI port; so for two screens I had the option of Dual DVI or HDMI to one and DVI to the other.

The base requirements are:

1. you have enough video ouputs and
2. your video ouputs match those of the displays.

Once connected, if you are running Windows, the likelyhood is that once connected, the displays will be mirrored.

You can switch between display on screen 1, screen 2, mirrored, and extended (what you want) using:
<kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

For more control over the display configuration, look for the display settings in the control panel.

Answer (score -2):

I've got two displays at the moment. The T.V is connected via HDMI and the VGA is connected to a basic display. You need an extra cable for sound via VGA which can come with the VGA cable sometimes but sometimes doesn't. I'd be connecting the better T.V with the HDMI and using that screen for movies/games etc and the display for times where graphics don't matter so much. 
It's also possible to get an HDMI splitter so you can go from one HDMI to two HDMI displays. I haven't used this myself so I'm not sure what sort of impact this would have on the graphics but I'd definitely give it a shot. 
Here's a link to amazon 'one in two out' HDMI splitter [https://www.amazon.com/HD-102-Powered-Splitter-Certified-Support/dp/B005HXFARS%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q%26tag%3Dduckduckgo-d-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB005HXFARS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HXFARS)

Comment: That just duplicates the output to two screens.  So no, not what the question is asking for.